# bash - here-document - problems with special characters together with double quotes despite the "repr"

Tags: bash, heredoc, ubuntu-22.04

Positive case:

```
set -- 'no " tabs' 'tab and double quotes   "'
repr="$(printf -- '%q ' "$@")"
echo "$repr"
```

Output:

```
no\ \"\ tabs $'tab and double quotes\t"'
```

Negative case:

```
bash -s <<- EOF
    repr="$(printf -- '%q ' "$@")"
    echo "\$repr"
EOF
```

Output:

```
bash: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: line 3: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Why?

**EDIT:** I need to keep parameter expansion enabled because in here-doc I also need to pass functions, terminal options and execute variables as commands.

Comment: `printf %q` already escapes the string for `bash -s`, so why do you surround it with `" "` in the hereoc?

Comment: @Fravadona You're right, that's why I modified the example to be more similar to my case, which answers the question of why I enclose the string in double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get the same result is to quote `EOF` :

```
set -- 'no " tabs' 'tab and double quotes   "'
bash -s "$@" <<-'EOF'
    repr="$(printf -- '%q ' "$@")"
    echo "$repr"
EOF
```

Comment: You don't need to keep parameter expansion enabled if you pass your parameters on the command line of the shell instead of its stdin

Comment: This solution is perfect but I need to keep parameter expansion enabled because in here-doc I also need to pass functions, terminal options and execute variables as commands and I have found a way to do it which you can read in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at what exactly the output of the here-doc is, with

```bash
cat -t <<- EOF
    repr="$(printf -- '%q ' "$norepr")"
    echo "\$repr"
EOF
```

you get this output:

```bash
    repr="$'tab and double quotes\t"' "
    echo "$repr"
```

Now, if you look at the first epxression:

```bash
repr="$'tab and double quotes\t"' "
```

you'll notice that these are unbalanced quotes:

```
repr="$'tab and double quotes\t"' "
     │││                      │││ │
     │└┴ literal $, ', and \t ┘││ │
     └──── syntactical " ──────┘│ │
        unclosed syntactical ' ─┘ │
                     literal " ───┘
```

For a simpler example, consider this:

```
$ a="$'abc\t'"
$ declare -p a
declare -- a="\$'abc\\t'"
```

Answer (score 0):

@Philippe Thank you, I have solved it!

```
set -- 'no " tabs' 'tab and double quotes   "'
echo "$repr"
bash -s "$@" <<- EOF
    repr="\$(printf -- '%q ' "\$@")"
    echo "\$repr"
EOF
```

Output:

```
no\ \"\ tabs $'tab and double quotes\t"'
no\ \"\ tabs $'tab and double quotes\t"'
```